# Incrementing one D array pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
 int a[3][2]={{4,7},{6,5},{9,1}};

 int i,j;
 clrscr();

 for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
   {
     printf("%d ",*(a[j]+i));
   }
 getch();
}
```

Here `a[i]` is of type int `(*)[2]`. So when we do `*(a[0]+1)`, it should go to next row and print 6 right? Why is it printing 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[0]` is an array of 2 ints with values `{4,7}`. It has the type `int[2]`. When used in most expressions, this automatically decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. type `int*` which points to the `4`. Incrementing this by one makes it point to the next `int`, which is  7.

A much clearer way to write `*(a[j]+i)` is `a[j][i]`. This does the same thing, because `p[x]` is defined to be `*(p+x)`.

Comment: Please help me with this thing :-   &a is of type int ( * ) [4][2].                                                                  *&a is of type int ( * ) [2], **&a is of type int * and ***&a is of type int. Am I correct? Which of these is a[j] ?

Comment: @Zephyr `&a` has type `int (*)[3][2]`. `*&a` has type `int[3][2]`, and can decay to `int (*)[2]`. `**&a` has type `int[2]` and can decay to `int*`. `a[j]` has type `int[2]` and can decay to `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

`a[j]` has type `int[2]` (not `int(*)[2]`) and it is one of `{4,7}`, `{6,5}` or `{9,1}`.

`a[0]` is the first element `{4,7}` and `a[0]+1` points at the second element of it, which is `7`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `int a[3][2];` not a **1D** array. it is a **2D** array. Incorrect your title.

`*(a[0]+1)` not incremented but `*(a[0]+1)` is equivalent `a[0][1]` and `a[0][1]` was `7`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear let's rewrite the definition of the array the following way

```
int a[3][2] = 
{
    { 4, 7 },
    { 6, 5 },
    { 9, 1}
};
```

Inside the inner loop that looks like

```
for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", *( a[j] + i ) );
}
```

for the index `i` equal to 0 there are used sequentially these expressions

```
*( a[0] + 0 )
*( a[1] + 0 )
*( a[2] + 0 )
```

that is the expression `a[j]` gives the j-th row and the first element of each row is outputted that is

```
4 6 9
```

Then in the outer loop the variable `j` is changed from `0` to `1` and we have the following expressions

```
*( a[0] + 1 )
*( a[1] + 1 )
*( a[2] + 1 )
```

So the second element of each row is outputted. As result we have

```
4 6 9 7 5 1
      |
      |-> the second iteration of the outer loop
```

Take into account hat `a[i]`  has the type `int[2]` that in expressions (with rare exceptions) is converted to the type `int *` and points to the first element of the array.

It is the array designator `a` used in expression is converted to pointer of the type `int ( * )[2]`.

So these expressions

```
*( a[0] + 0 )
*( a[1] + 0 )
*( a[2] + 0 )
```

could be rewritten in the form

```
*( *( a + j ) + i )
```